# Flutter Web iOS : universal html stretching taken picture with the iphone camera after uploading

Tags: html, ios, iphone, flutter, flutter-web

I'm building a flutter web app. when I pick a picture from the gallery it **looks scaled** but when I **take the picture using the iphone camera** the image being **stretched on preview**

**Example:**

[Redicrection to the image I want to upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzKzF.png)

[Redirection to the preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3KV6.png)

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Generally, it is easier for other people to answer your question if you share the code that is giving you problems. In this case, for example, I'd add the whole code you're using to import a picture taken from the camera.

Comment: @MrAsterisco
the code is in this question : [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61592902/taken-picture-stretched-only-in-ios-devices-flutter-web)

Comment: I put the code in this Question : [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61592902/taken-picture-stretched-only-in-ios-devices-flutter-web)